# Plot Two Line Series on One Graph

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

I am trying to plot two lines series on a chart.  Each line with have different times for their data points.  Unfortunately, the code below produces a weird result (probably because the there is not a timestamp for the current level line).  Is there another chart type or way that I can fix this issue of the current level going down to zero each target level?

Here is my xaml:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Glucose and Target Levels" x:Name="LevelsChart">
    <chartingToolkit:StackedLineSeries>

        <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition Title="Actual"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=GlucoseLevels}"
                                          IndependentValuePath="Timestamp"
                                          DependentValuePath="Level" />

        <chartingToolkit:SeriesDefinition Title="Target"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=TargetLevels}"
                                          IndependentValuePath="Timestamp"
                                          DependentValuePath="Level" />
    </chartingToolkit:StackedLineSeries>

    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

        <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis x:Name="LevelsDateTimeAxis" Orientation="X" Minimum="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=Minimum}" Maximum="{Binding ElementName=PatientWindow, Path=Maximum}" />

        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Interval="20" />

    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Post the code in which you fill the GlucoseLevels property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StackedLineSeries` is not what want and is in fact what is causing you problems.  That kind of chart adds the series together vertically to create a total for each independent axis value.  Instead just add each `LineSeries` directly to the `Chart`.